# Proof of theorem about iterative methods

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How do I prove that if $A$ is a tridiagonal (or block tridiagonal) matrix then the corresponding $P_J$ and $P_G$ iteration matrices for the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods satisfy that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P_J$ then $\sqrt{\lambda}$ (plus or minus?) is one of $P_G$ and if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P_G$ then $\lambda^2$ is one of $P_J$, and therefore the two methods either both converge or non converges and Gauss-Seidel is twice as fast as Jacobi? This theorem has been given to me in University without demonstration, but then on $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ I obtained the most unexpected result: that Jacobi converged and Gauss-Seidel didn't. Since I can't see any error in the implementation of the algorithms, I can either question this theorem or suppose there is some huge algorithmic error at work, so how do I prove that theorem? And is it true in the first place?

Comment: I noticed that my implementation of the Gauss-Seidel method was mistaken, and correcting that mistake brought me to the expected result. Anyway, since I've posted the question, could someone answer it?

Comment: This is known as the Stein-Rosenberg theorem. You can find its proof [here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ix__1MNMHfIC&lpg=PP1&dq=varga%20iterative&hl=cs&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: First of all, why go for French Google books with "extra info" in Czech? Best keep everything in English: [see here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ix__1MNMHfIC&lpg=PP1&dq=varga%20iterative&hl=en&pg=PA74#v=onepage&q&f=false). Secondly, no matter what language combination I choose, page 76 is never part of the preview, and the proof seems to be exactly on that page.

Comment: First of all, you are welcome. Secondly, the book is still in english and no matter what language I choose, page 76 is always a part of the preview (for me). Anyway, there are alternatives where to look for the proof when one knows its authors (e.g., [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Stein+Rosenberg+theorem)), the [original paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-23/2/111.extract), or other books dealing with stationary iterative methods (e.g., [this one](http://books.google.fr/books?id=rajDAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA120&dq=varga%20iterative&hl=iw&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: Please refrain from posting Google books, because by Murphy's law you can be sure the preview for me will _never_ have that proof. The original paper needs a subscription to the Journal of the London Mathematical Society for download, which I surely don't have. Googling leads [here](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Stein+Rosenberg+theorem&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: Now result 1 appears to be unsearchable, and I definitely don't have the time to read through it all. Result 2 has a different theorem from what I asked about under the name Stein-Rosenberg theorem. And it has no proof of that either, apparently. Same applies to result 3. Result 4 seems to be the same as result 2. Result 5 is the first google book you posted. Result 6 has the same defect as 3 and 4, and the same title. Results 7-8 state they are generalizations of the theorem. Result 9 has the same problem as 3, 4 and 6. In general, these results all point in one direction: …

Comment: The theorem I'm asking about is NOT the Stein-Rosenberg theorem.

Comment: The Stein-Rosenberg theorem states that if $A$ has positive diagonal entries and non-positive non-diagonal entries, then either $0\leq\rho(P_G)<\rho(P_G)<1$, or $1<\rho(P_J)<\rho(P_G)$, or they are both $1$ or $0$. My theorem states that if $A$ is tridiagonal, then the eigenvalues of $P_J$ are the square roots of those of $P_G$, and those of $P_G$ are the squares of those of $P_J$, thus leading to $\rho(P_J)^2=\rho(P_G)$. Now it is clear that they "intersect", in a way, as in some cases they state the same thing about the convergence, but they are definitely NOT the same theorem.

Comment: Theorem 9.2.5 [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~flaherje/pdf/pde9.pdf) and Remark 3 on page 21.

Comment: How do you prove a block tridiagonal matrix is consistently ordered? And thanks for the reference :).

Comment: You can show the property for any Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix. Say, $A=\mathrm{tridiag}(\gamma,1,\delta)$ and let $D(L+U)x=\lambda x$ with $x=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^T$ (WLOG one can assume $D=I$ as here). Try to show that $D(\alpha L+1/\alpha U)y=\lambda y$, where $y=[y_1,\ldots,y_n]^T$, $y_i=\alpha ^ix_i$. HINT: $D(L+U)x=\lambda x$ is equivalent to $-\gamma x_{i-1}-\delta x_{i+1}=\lambda x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ ($x_0=x_{n+1}=0$ for convenience).

Comment: +1 for that. Let me just post a reminder for myself: WLOG = SPDG = Without Loss Of Generality.